# What's the difference between npm update and npm install @latest in npm 5.5?

Tags: node.js, npm

In the documentation for [npm update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update), it says that when used on global packages, like `npm update package-name -g`, it will update to the @latest. This did not work for me.

I resorted to `npm install package-name@latest -g` which did update to the latest version as I intended.

Am I missing something here? I thought they both do the same thing, but one did not.

Comment: By chance are you certain that the package you were attempting to update was already globally installed?
For example if you had installed the package using `npm install package-name` and then tried to update using `npm update package-name -g` that would not work as the package was installed to the node_modules folder relative to the directory that you ran the command from.

Comment: @varubi I am sure.

Answer (score 1):

> **npm update** updates all packages in the node_modules directory of the project or if you specify the -g tag then in global dependencies
>   and their dependencies. It will only update to the latest stable release
>
> **npm latest** will update the dependencies but if there is any latest version that is in beta or pre-release it will update to that as well